# Make a projected image smaller?

Tags: optics, lenses, vision, imaging

A friend has a Batman nightlight that projects Batman onto her ceiling. She has vision problems because of a head injury. She could see Batman fine when she was in an upstairs bedroom and the ceiling was higher. She has had to move downstairs to a smaller room with a lower ceiling. She can no longer see Batman. She sees a blob of light. Is there some lens I can project the image through that would make Batman smaller so that she can see that it's actually Batman? Or bigger? I might need to try it both ways to see which works.

Comment: Some clarification needed here: Are you saying that only your friend has problems seeing the Batman image on the lower ceiling (due to her vision problems) or are you saying that even anyone with normal vision would have a problem seeing the image on the lower ceiling? In particular, does the image on the lower ceiling look fine to you when you look at it?

Comment: @SamuelWeir That is the issue. I can see Batman fine. She can't. It doesn't matter if anyone else can see it but her. The only difference is the lower ceiling from where it's plugged in is the lower ceiling. Even on the higher ceiling she saw two of them. But she could see it was Batman. Now she sees two blobs of light.

Comment: Sounds like the problem is partly far-sightedness. If so, how about projecting the image horizontally along the length of the room to the wall on the far side (assuming that that distance is greater than the ceiling height). Or, if she really wants to see the image on the ceiling a wild idea would be to mount mirrors on both the ceiling and the floor so that the projected beam bounces up to the ceiling mirror, then down to the floor mirror, then up to a blank area of the ceiling where she can see the image. That effectively triples the ceiling height.

Comment: That's all I can think of from a physicist's perspective. Otherwise, have her see a good optometrist or ophthalmologist about this problem.

Comment: We're waiting for her Medicaid to get turned back on to go to the eye doctor. The mirror has possibilities. Thanks! Oh, and it's a perfectly square room. :(

Comment: Actually, depending on the extra apparent ceiling height that you need to get close to the height of the upstairs bedroom, you might be able to get away with something simpler. For example, put one small mirror very close to the output of the projector so that it turns the light beam 90-degrees to a horizontal direction, and then another larger mirror that catches that light and then bounces it up to the ceiling. Optically, that would increase the apparent height of the room by a distance equal to the separation between the two mirrors.

Comment: Oh, wait. Scratch that last comment. It's not enough that the apparent optical path of from the projector to the image increases. The apparent optical path between the girl and the image also has to increase (i.e., the image has to appear to be farther away to her.). So she needs to view the image by looking at it through the mirrors. Probably will need to use moderately large mirrors for this idea.

Answer (score 0):

Finding a special lens will be difficult and complicated. Get a extension cord and plug the nightlight into it. Now shine the image the on the walls or ceiling until you obtain an image your friend can see and enjoy. Find a way to mount the light in that location. That's what I would do. Good luck.

Comment: I tried moving it to different plugins. That didn't change the size of it any. She still couldn't see it. I do like this idea. I may have to try hanging it from the ceiling.